# Converting python dictionary into an INSERT query

Tags: python, dictionary, psycopg2

```
def insert_data(data):
    cur = self.database_connectivity(db_name, host)
    columns = ', '.join(data.keys())
    val = ', '.join(data.values())
    qry = f"INSERT INTO test_table({columns}) Values ({val})"
    print(qry)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    query = sqlOpr()
    query.insert_data({"id": "123abc", "status": "f"})
```

This gives me the output as :-

```
INSERT INTO test_table(id, status) Values (123abc, f)
```

But I want the output as:-

```
INSERT INTO test_table(id, status) Values ("123abc", "f")
```

I want the values as separate strings for my query to be executed.

Any help?

Comment: What library are you using for your database connection & query?

Comment: @PacketLoss: I am using postgresSql DB and using python library psycopg2

Comment: My solutions works almost perfectly apart from the string it forms for the values. I want the values to be formed as separate strings within a string. like this:-
INSERT INTO test_table(id, status) Values ("123abc", "f")

Comment: @sam: Psycopg2 does everything for you: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: @sam That sounds as if you are duplicating things psycopg2 already does. Do your solutions also take care of sql injections and other security threats that are taken care of when using normal psycopg2 features for everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def insert_data(data):
    cur = self.database_connectivity(db_name, host)
    columns = ', '.join(data.keys())
    val = tuple(data.values())
    qry = f"INSERT INTO test_table({columns}) Values {val}"
    cur.execute(qry)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    query = sqlOpr()
    query.insert_data({"id": "123abc", "status": "f"})
```

Comment: I Converted it into a tuple and it worked fine for me